# RecyclerView doesn't complete scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview in a coordinator view, the recyclerview is in a fragment in a framelayout and below an appbarlayout, here is the layout description

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/coordinator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:id="@+id/fragmentFrame"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="snap|enterAlways|scroll">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

.

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);
```

Whenever I perform a smoothscrolltoposition, it doesn't complete the scroll, there is a little offset in the bottom with the height of the action bar height. Any subsequent call to smoothscrolltoposition has the same offset. But if I perform the scroll to hide the toolbar then it is okay and there is no offset.

How can I force the recyclerview to scroll completely. I am using this together with `stackFromEnd`.

Comment: i don't see RecyclerView  in your layout

Comment: @PankajNimgade the recyclerview is in a fragment in a framelayout

Answer (score 0):

**AppBarLayout** has a method which appears just in **23 api** version :

```
setExpanded(boolean expanded)
```

Check its description on developers.android : [AppBarLayout.setExpanded](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html#setExpanded(boolean))

Also I found an interesting example on GitHub : [setExpanded example](https://github.com/PPartisan/ScrollHandleExample)

I had the same situation when trying to execute smoothScrollToPosition :  RecyclerView scrolled as usual, but AppBarLayout doesn't scroll at all. I had to scroll manually to hide AppBarLayout and scroll to the last list element.

I hope this answer will save someone's day, which I spent tying to find a solution.